# Node JS avoid laboriously adding "use strict" to all my files

Tags: javascript, node.js, strict

So I want to enable strict mode for my project, but I have a lot of files and adding `"use strict";` to the top of all of them would be a pain. I discovered the `--use_strict` CLI option for node which is awesome, but enables it for every single file inside my project directory, including all the third-party modules and their modules and I really don't want to go through correcting everybody's files, just mine.

So my question is, is there a way I could automate adding "use strict" to only my files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a script that opens each file and adds `"use strict"\n` to the beginning of it and write it back to disk.

Very untested example:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
   files = fs.readDirSync('./'),
   i;

for (i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
  var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files[i]).toString();
  fileContent = "\"use strict\"\n" + fileContent;
  fs.appendFileSync(files[i], fileContent);
}
```

Test for `file[i]` being a directory and move to a function to make it recursive if you need.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11987281/85010 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559790/85010.

Comment: Thanks. I enhanced your example with a check if `use strict` already exists in the file, and glob pattern matching: https://gist.github.com/blaise-io/b011f63a3f6624816fad. I hope someone may find it useful.

Comment: @maxheiber According to [the documentation of fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), there is no function called `readDirStrict`. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 2):

**use-strict-cli** is a Node.js command line tool for adding/removing `"use strict"` statements within files found in given directories.

**Instructions can be found here:**

https://github.com/philidem/use-strict-cli

**Example usage to add missing `"use strict`" statements:**

use-strict ./src

**Example usage to remove missing `"use strict"` statements:**

use-strict ./src --remove

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you adopt [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) in your work cycle and let it do this for you, amongst a bunch of other useful checks that will guarantee good-quality code.

I maintain a `.jshintrc` at the root of my web project with options:

```
{
  "immed": true,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "nonew": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "multistr": true,
  "devel": true
}
```

You see that `strict: true` is in fact missing. This is because jshint has it set to `true` by default :)

Then you can have jshint setup to run as a git pre-commit hook or even better install it as a plugin for your code editor and fix the errors in real time as you code (e.g. [SublimeLinter package](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) for Sublime text 3)

Comment: I beg to differ. On the github page of jshint, there is a sample `.jshintrc` with the default values for all options and `strict` is shown as `true`. It can be found here: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc

Comment: i saw that - but it is not correct.  try it out:  create a global `x=10;` in your code and run jshint with and without `strict: true` (and nothing else in .jshintrc).  it will not report the global (ie, does not apply the strict rules).  maybe this is a bug, but the docs certainly aren't clear on what the default behaviour is.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. You are right. It would be nice if you would report it to the [maintainer of jshint](http://stackoverflow.com/users/71701/anton-kovalyov). I have been misled by the docs :(

Comment: no worries - it is a shame that the docs aren't more clear.  in some regards, it would not be correct to enforce the same rules; the addition of `"use strict";` in your code changes the rules of allowable javascript.  anyway, i hope this knowledge means you can find more bugs before they bite you.