# How to push JS object to JSON in new line?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file

How modified this function to add every object in file's new line?

```
   exports.addWaypoint = function(id, type, param){
        var dataIn = fs.readFileSync('./markers.json');
        var obj = JSON.parse(dataIn);          
        obj.markers.push({
            "id": id,
            "type": type,
            "param": param,
        });           
        writeJson(obj);    
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js read and write file lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986350/node-js-read-and-write-file-lines)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a duplicate of [Javascript: How to generate formatted easy-to-read JSON straight from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515523/javascript-how-to-generate-formatted-easy-to-read-json-straight-from-an-object)

Here's a quick answer: use JSON.stringify with an optional parameter to indicate the indention for each nested element.

```
var o = {
    "id": 123,
    "type": "good",
    "param": { name: "Fred", age: 24 },
};

console.log( JSON.stringify(o,null,4) );
```