# Protractor - Create a txt file as report with the "Expect..." result

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to create a report for my scenario, I want to execute some validations and add the retults in a string, then, write this string in a TXT file (for each validation I would like to add the result and execute again till the last item), something like this:

```
it ("Perform the loop to search for different strings", function() 
{        
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

browser.get("http://WebSite.es");

//strings[] contains 57 strings inside the json file

    for (var i = 0; i == jsonfile.strings.length ; ++i) 
    {
        var valuetoInput = json.Strings[i];
        var writeInFile;
        browser.wait;
        httpGet("http://website.es/search/offers/list/"+valuetoInput+"?page=1&pages=3&limit=20").then(function(result) {
            writeInFile = writeInFile + "Validation for String: "+ json.Strings[i] + " Results is: " + expect(result.statusCode).toBe(200) + "\n";
        });

        if (i == jsonfile.strings.length)
        {
            console.log("Executions finished");
            var fs = require('fs');
            var outputFilename = "Output.txt";
            fs.writeFile(outputFilename, "Validation of Get requests with each string:\n " + writeInFile, function(err) {
                if(err) 
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("File saved to " + outputFilename);
                }
                });
        }
      };
});
```

But when I check my file I only get the first row writen in the way I want and nothing else, could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

*The validation works properly in the screen for each of string in my file used as data base

**I'm a newbie with protractor

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[writeFile documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already
>   exists

You are overwriting the file every time, which is why it only has 1 line.

The easiest way would probably (my opinion) be [appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback).  It writes to a file without overwriting existing data and will also create the file if it doesnt exist in the first place.

You could also re-read that log file, store that data in a variable, and re-write to that file with the old AND new data included in it.   You could also create a [writeStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) etc.

There are quite a few ways to go about it and plenty of other answers 
 on SO specifically on those functions that can provide more info.

[Node.js Write a line into a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418777/node-js-write-a-line-into-a-txt-file)

[Node.js read and write file lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986350/node-js-read-and-write-file-lines/11987281)

Final note, if you are using Jasmine you can also create a [custom jasmine reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html).  They have methods that contain exactly what you want (status Pass/Fail, actual vs expected values etc) and it's fairly easy to set up with Protractor

Comment: Worked with appendFile! I had to change the code a little bit but now I'm able to get what I want. thank you!